# How to add boost unit test framework in autotools C++

Tags: c++, autotools, automake

I have a C++ project and I'm trying to figure out how to get autotools to include the `-lboost_unit_test_framework` flag dynamically during the build process. If I add it and compile manually using `g++` it builds, it's just missing the flag when setting up the makefiles using autotools.

Also, when running `./configure` it returns:
`./configure: line 3113: AX_BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK: command not found`

My configure.ac:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([project], [0.1.0], [example@example.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/main.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX

# Checks for libraries.
AX_BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK

# Checks for header files.

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

# Checks for library functions.

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile
                 src/Makefile
                 test/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, the macro is undefined unless you download it from the [autoconf-archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive). I placed it in my project here `project/m4`.

Also, you have to tell `configure.ac` where to find them:

```
...
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4]) # << Add this line

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
...
```

**Update:**

Once I got this working, to get `make check` to execute the tests, I had to:

1. Add this to the `project/test/Makefile.am`:

   ```
   check_PROGRAMS = program_tests
   program_tests_CPPFLAGS = -I../src/ ${BOOST_CPPFLAGS}
   program_tests_LDFLAGS = ${BOOST_LDFLAGS}
   program_wallet_tests_LDADD = ${BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIB}
   program_wallet_tests_SOURCES = runner.cpp main_tests.cpp
   ```
2. Add this line to the main `project/Makefile.am`:
   `TESTS = test/program_tests`

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.  For future readers, a key clue here was that the name of the macro you wanted to use starts with `AX_`.  This is a sure sign that it isn't provided by the Autoconf distribution itself, and a likely indicator that the macro is available from the Autoconf archive.